# Get Sibling using Xpath

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath

I'm trying to verify is a checkbox is checked or not and trying to build a robust xpath. I need to figure out how to transverse from 'Password Never Expires' text to img scr with attribute title?

[image: Elements inspection tr]

Comment: Share HTML sample as simple text, your current XPath, current and desired output

Answer (score 1):

You first need to select the `td` that has the text 'Password Never Expires', this is quite straightforward:

```
//td[text()='Password Never Expires']
```

When you have this element you can use the Axis `[following-sibling][1]` to get the following `td` node:

```
following-sibling::td
```

Now you have the node that contains the `img` node, all you have to do now is to get the `@src` attribute of this node:

```
img[@title='Checked']/@src
```

Putting all the above together will give you:

```
//td[text()='Password Never Expires']/following-sibling::td/img[@title='Checked']/@src
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @BlueGunner Great, you can mark the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Xpath :

```
//td[contains(@class,'Never Expires')]/parent::td//following-sibling::td[@class='dataCol']/img
```

try out ! and let me know if it works for you or not.